# Is there any API that allow to track object changes in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Does anybody know if there are any solution like 'Hibernate History API' for entity framework.
If no, may be there are some history tracking practise/patterns applied to EF. I'm newbie to EF so far. Any refs are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

EF version 4 has Self Tracking Entities. They track their changes and can be attached back to a different context to be saved. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

This is new to EF. The first version did not have this functionality.

Comment: I don't need diff context. I mean that i need snapshot of the object's previous state. If i going to STE then i lose some features such as lazy loading and others.

Comment: Furthermore, It's just another one implementation for the generation of the objects with built-in abilities to track changes in most for remoting. My question was if there are some features in EF akin to  'Hibernate History API'  http://labs.micromata.de/display/hh/Home with handy APIs to track changes. Or may be there are some third party providers.
Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ObjectContext.SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx). You can handle this and then walk the modified/etc. members in `ObjectStateManager`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a roll back feature then it is not supported. However you have the option to retrieve the original and current value of a property and relationship. For instance for customer i would do this

db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(customer).CurrentValues["Name"]
db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(customer).Original["Name"]